# Regular expression which cannot be used

Tags: regex

I want extract C-like comments from source, f.e. from

(updated example)

```
/**
 * base comment
 * (c) SOMEBODY SOMETIME
 * something
 */

///<!-- ------metadata-XML------- -->
/// <module type="javascript"> A
///<desc> some desc 
///      </desc> 
(function( a /* param A */) { // programmers comment ... enclosure
/*! user doc
 this module ....
 * reguired
.....
*/
var b={}; // programmers in line comment
// single line comments

// The cookie spec says up to 4k per cookie, so at ~50 bytes per entry
// that gives a maximum of around 80 items as a max value for this field
    b.a=a;
    var str = " tttt \/\/this is not comment ! tttt "
    var str2 = " tttt \/\* this is not comment too ! \
.............. \*\/ ttt ";
    global.b = b; 
}(global);
///</module>
```

regexp which I use is

```
^\s*\/\*(.*[\r\n]*)*\*\/
```

Problem is that this regexp stops (kills) regexp engine. RegexCouch becomes unresponsible,
using in browser causes unresponsible page.

What is wrong with this regexp ? How is possible, that regexp engine cannot solve it ? 
Are there some regexp-es (syntactically correct, I think) which cannot be used ?

Comment: What final language will you use?

Comment: 1. PHP ... support PCRE, 2. javascript in browser or NodeJs ... without PCRE

Answer (score 5):

This is called [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Your regex has to check to many possibilities, because you are nesting quantifiers:

```
^\s*\/\*(.*[\r\n]*)*\*\/
         ^^      ^ ^
```

A better approach would be this:

```
/^\s*\/\*.*?\*\//gms
```

See it [here in action](http://www.regex101.com/r/cW3xA7).

You need the `s` option to make the `.` match the newline, the `m` option to make the `^` matches the start of he row.

`.*?` is matching as less characters as possible.

Comment: Your suggested regex seems to grab more lines than it should with a single match. http://www.regex101.com/r/xK4lT3

Comment: I tried to fix only the Catastrophic Backtracking. This regex has other problems too.

Answer (score 2):

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```

this will work for c-like comments match

Comment: unless they're in strings \o/

Comment: @suppid I was tested at my side , it is working fine for me,  that's why I was given to you .Nice to hear the same from your end ...

Answer (score 1):

if you use pcre-like regex you can use this:

```
\s*+\/\*(?>[^*]++|\*++(?!\/))*\*\/
```

if your regex flavor doesn't support atomic groups and possessive quantifiers, use this:

```
\s*\/\*(?:[^*]+|\*+(?!\/))*\*\/
```

Comment: second regexp  kills RegexCoach and browser (Google Chrome) too

Comment: @stupid: strange, i'm not sure it's due to the regex. Try another regex tester: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/